# gvim(linux) with r-plugin not recognizing .R files with comments

Tags: r, vim, vim-plugin

Note: rewrote the original question to reflect the proper solution given.

vim (ubuntu 12.04 w/ r-plugin) doesn't recognize .R or .r files as R files with the r-plugin installed with a comment in the file as shown below.

```
# comment
x <- 2
x
```

Without the comment, everything works fine.
my ~/.vim/filetype.vim reads:

```
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.r         setfiletype r
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.R         setfiletype r
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.Rnw       setf noweb
augroup END
```

Comment: Could you provide two sample files, one that works and one that doesn't?

Comment: Thanks Thor, after trying to create two equivalent files for this example, I realized the file in question started with a comment. I will add to the question above to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple file types seem to use the `R` extension. I found this in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`:

```
" Rexx, Rebol or R
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.r,*.R           call s:FTr()

func! s:FTr()
let max = line("$") > 50 ? 50 : line("$")

for n in range(1, max)
    " Rebol is easy to recognize, check for that first
    if getline(n) =~? '\<REBOL\>'
    setf rebol
    return
    endif
endfor

for n in range(1, max)
    " R has # comments
    if getline(n) =~ '^\s*#'
    setf r
    return
    endif
    " Rexx has /* comments */
    if getline(n) =~ '^\s*/\*'
    setf rexx
    return
    endif
endfor

" Nothing recognized, assume Rexx
setf rexx
endfunc
```

So you need to have comments in the file for Vim to properly detect R.

In case you never use Rexx or Rebol files, you can override the detection:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.r,*.R setf r
```

Comment: my ~/.vim/filetype.vim file currently reads:                         augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.r         setfiletype r
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.R         setfiletype r
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.Rnw       setf noweb
augroup END
Shouldn't that address it?

Comment: Added that to the original question so the formatting shows better.

Comment: marking this as correct in that it resolved the problem...my actual solution was to change "setfiletype r" to "setfiletype=r" but the above will work just as well.